# Array Serialization in Axis

Tags: java, soap, axis

I have encountered a strange problem when calling a web service. My stubs generate soap message like in format 2 however server expects something like in format 1 below. 
In arrayserialization in axis 1.3 what is the meaning of following formats.

Below arrayItemType is Object type whics is being serialized and arrayItemName is the name of that  object.

1)

```
 <arrayItemName>
  <arrayItemType></arrayItemType>
  <arrayItemType></arrayItemType>
 </arrayItemName>
```

2)

```
<arrayItemName>
</arrayItemName>
<arrayItemName>
</arrayItemName>
```

Answer (score 1):

The question what style is your WSDL file? SOAP document depends on style used in WSDL file.

The first format is wrapped style, because elements is wrapped within:

`<arrayItemName> ... </arrayItemName>`

So I guess that if your stubs generates soap message like in format 2 it uses rpc/encoded or any other WSDL styles except the wrapped one. So I suggest you always use **document/literal wrapped** style for wsdl files and there will be any problems when generating clients using different stacks or etc.

You can find useful information about WSDL styles here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/